# Limits of inf and sup in a set

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, supremum-and-infimum

I'm stuck on a problem where I have the following,

> $A \subset \mathbb R$. Then there exists sequence ${a_{n}}$ and ${b_{n}}$ of  $A$ such that
> $$\lim_{n \to \infty}{a_{n}}=\sup(A),\ \ \ \ \lim_{n \to \infty}{b_{n}}=\inf(A).$$

I have a small outline of the proof that I have done however I'm not exactly sure if this is the right way to go,

I want to find a sequence $x_n$ in $\mathbb R$ such that $x_n<\sup(A)$ for each $n$ and $x_n\to a$ and if $\alpha=\sup(A)<\infty$ I let $x_n=\alpha-\frac{1}{n}$ and if $\sup(A)=\infty$ then I'll let $x_n=n$. I also would follow this same pattern for the $\inf(A)$ since $\sup(A)=-\inf(-A)$.

Or would it be better to show that $a_n$ is increasing in $A$ and $b_n$ is increasing in $A$ and since both sequences are part of $A$ we know they are bounded both above and below so $sup(A)$ and $inf(A)$ exists so I can use that to prove the initial proof.

Any help is welcomed.

Comment: Please rewrite (so edit) what you meant by "$A \subset \mathbb R$ where ${a_{n}}$ are sequences ${b_{n}}$ in $A$." more clearly. As it stands, your sentence is 'somewhat opaque.' Thanks...

Comment: Ahh thank you, I can see where the confusion was. It is fixed now.

Comment: Do you mean "Suppose $A\subset {\mathbb R}$. I want to prove that there exists sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ in $A$ such that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = \sup A \text{ and }\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n = \inf A."$$

Comment: Yes that is correct, I'm sorry English is not my first language so I struggle with it at times.

Comment: For example for every $n\in\mathbb N$ by definition of the supremum there is an $a_n\in A$ such that $\sup A -\frac1n\le a_n\le\sup A$

Comment: To point out what is wrong with your sketched argument in your question: how do you know in your example that $\alpha - 1/n \in A$?  It doesn't have to be, right? e.g., $A = [0,1] \setminus \{1-1/k \mid k=1,2,\cdots\}$. Take a look, instead, at @MaximilianJanisch's approach